# Terraform key vault access policy

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to automate she creation of a key vault, storage account and key to encrypt the storage.

The code of block looks like this:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "storage" {
  for_each = toset(var.storage-foreach)
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.tenantsnbshared.id
  tenant_id = <tenant-id>
  object_id    = azurerm_storage_account.storage-foreach[each.value]
  key_permissions    = ["get", "create", "list", "restore", "recover", "unwrapkey", "wrapkey", "purge", "encrypt", "decrypt", "sign", "verify"]
  secret_permissions = ["get"]
  depends_on = [azurerm_storage_account.storage-foreach]
}

esource "azurerm_key_vault" "tenantsnbshared" {
  location                        = var.location
  name                            = "tenantsnbshared"
  resource_group_name             = azurerm_resource_group.tenant-testing-test.name
  sku_name                        = "standard"
  tenant_id                       = "tenant-id"
  enabled_for_deployment          = false
  enabled_for_disk_encryption     = false
  enabled_for_template_deployment = false
  purge_protection_enabled        = true
  soft_delete_enabled             = true
  access_policy {
    object_id = "my-obj-id"
    tenant_id = "tenant-id"
    secret_permissions = [
      "Get",
      "List",
      "Set",
      "Delete",
      "Recover",
      "Backup",
      "Restore",
      "Purge"

    ]
    key_permissions = [
      "Get",
      "List",
      "Update",
      "Create",
      "Import",
      "Delete",
      "Recover",
      "Backup",
      "Restore",
      "Purge",
      "encrypt",
      "decrypt",
      "sign",
      "verify"
    ]
    certificate_permissions = [
      "Get",
      "List",
      "Update",
      "Create",
      "Import",
      "Delete",
      "Recover",
      "Backup",
      "Restore",
      "ManageContacts",
      "ManageIssuers",
      "GetIssuers",
      "ListIssuers",
      "SetIssuers",
      "DeleteIssuers",
    ]
  }
  tags = {
    "Owner" : "test"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage-foreach" {
  for_each                 = toset(var.storage-foreach)
  access_tier              = "Hot"
  account_kind             = "StorageV2"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  location                 = var.location
  name                     = each.value
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.tenant-testing-hamza.name
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = false
  }
}
```

As you can see all the resource works with a for each to automate the process.
But when I try to run this code, I got this error related to the key_vault_access_policy

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on main.tf line 13, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "storage":
  13:   object_id    = azurerm_storage_account.storage-foreach[each.value]
    |----------------
    | azurerm_storage_account.storage-foreach is object with 2 attributes
    | each.value is "storage2"

Inappropriate value for attribute "object_id": string required.
```

Answer (score 2):

You should assign the `object ids of storage accounts` to the KV access policies.

Kindly change the access policy resource to the following:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "storage" {
  for_each = toset(var.storage-foreach)

  ...

  object_id    = azurerm_storage_account.storage-foreach[each.value].0.principal_id

  ...    
}
```

Comment: It's needed .. it points to the first identity of the storage account, not the storage itself ..

Comment: okay, got it, simply did not know that in this case.

Comment: no prob .. just in case I'm leaving an azurerm_key_vault_access_policy example here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account_customer_managed_key

Comment: Sorry I was heading back home. I tried you code and the error is as follow:
```
n main.tf line 21, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "storage":
  21:   depends_on = [azurerm_storage_account.storage-foreach[each.value]]

A single static variable reference is required: only attribute access and
indexing with constant keys. No calculations, function calls, template
expressions, etc are allowed here.
```

Comment: hmm ok .. I think you can simply remove the depends_on block ..  there is already an implicit dependency between the access policy and the storage since you assign the storage's object id to the access policy ..

Comment: And here is the weird thing. Because I tried to remove the depends on. but I get this error:  "The given key does not identify an element in this collection value." I am sorry man, but really don't know how to go around this bit

Comment: I'm afk but seeing that there's an open GitHub issue about the topic: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/25578

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I managed to go around that error, just to face this one:
"Code="InvalidValuesForRequestParameters" Message="Values for request parameters are invalid: encryption.keyvaultproperties" Which I was reading is a X509_certificate_property that should be added in the certificate. But I don't find any way to implement it or where exactly